# How to create a DOM node as an object?

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like to create a DOM node, set the 'id' attribute and then append it to 'body'. The following seems not to work because jQuery doesn't see my template as an object:

```
var template = "<li><div class='bar'>bla</div></li>";
template.find('li').attr('id','1234');
$(body).append(template);
```

How can I tell jQuery to treat this as an object so find() works on it?

Comment: it doesn't work because you are applying find within the dom element you created. In this case you are trying to find `li`underneath `li`, however there is only a `div` and text `bla`. Try something like this to understand what happens `var template=$("<div><li><div>bla</div></li></div>")`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I'd put it in the DOM first. I'm not sure why my first example failed. That's really weird.

```
var e = $("<ul><li><div class='bar'>bla</div></li></ul>");
$('li', e).attr('id','a1234');  // set the attribute 
$('body').append(e); // put it into the DOM
```

Putting e (the returns elements) gives jQuery [context](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) under which to apply the CSS selector. This keeps it from applying the ID to other elements in the DOM tree.

The issue appears to be that you aren't using the UL. If you put a naked li in the DOM tree, you're going to have issues. I thought it could handle/workaround this, but it can't.

You may not be putting naked LI's in your DOM tree for your "real" implementation, but the UL's are necessary for this to work. Sigh.

Example:
http://jsbin.com/iceqo

By the way, you may also be interested in [microtemplating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).

Comment: You're setting the attribute after the object has been appended... My tests say this doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, it broke for me as well. Weird. I thought I had run it through. Anyway, this version works.

Comment: It works, but if your body has more than one 'li' then the attribute is added to all of these... Maybe adding :last will do.

Comment: No it won't, that's why the e is there to specify context.

Comment: Oh hell, it didn't use the context. What a day.

Comment: Don't understand, you DO set the contents: $('li',e), but that doesn't do anything...

Comment: Any idea how to set an ID on the parent element - e.g. <ul> in this case? It doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
var div = $('<div></div>').addClass('bar').text('bla');
var li = $('<li></li>').attr('id', '1234');
li.append(div);

$('body').append(li);
```

Obviously, it doesn't make sense to append a li to the body directly. Basically, the trick is to construct the DOM elementr tree with $('your html here'). I suggest to use CSS modifiers (.text(), .addClass() etc) as opposed to making jquery parse raw HTML, it will make it much easier to change things later.

Comment: @TamasCzinege, in li.append(div) why div is appended to li ?

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15):

```
var template = $( "<li>", { id: "1234", html:
  $( "<div>", { class: "bar", text: "bla" } )
});
$('body').append(template);
```

What about this?

Answer (score 3):

First make your template into a jQuery object:

```
 var template = $("<li><div class='bar'>bla</div></li>");
```

Then set the attributes and append it to the DOM.

```
 template.find('li').attr('id','1234');
 $(document.body).append(template);
```

Note that it however makes no sense at all to add a li directly to the DOM since li should always be children of ul or ol. Also it is better to not make jQuery parse raw HTML. Instead create a li, set its attributes. Create a div and set it's attributes. Insert the div into the li and then append the li to the DOM.

Comment: I would think that _sshould_ work, but it doesn't. (it's in fact exactly what I posted first) see: http://jsbin.com/eware

Answer (score 3):

And here is the one liner:

```
$("<li><div class='bar'>bla</div></li>").find("li").attr("id","1234").end().appendTo("body")
```

But I'm wondering why you would like to add the "id" attribute at a later stage rather than injecting it directly in the template.

Comment: This doesn't work, we've been down the road before. I'm wondering if it's a bug, because it really seems like it ought to work, and a number of people have ran into this .

Answer (score 2):

There are three reasons why your example fails.

1. The original 'template' variable is not a jQuery/DOM object and cannot be parsed, it is a string. Make it a jQuery object by wrapping it in $(), such as: template = $(template)
2. Once the 'template' variable is a jQuery object you need to realize that <li> is the root object. Therefore you cannot search for the LI root node and get any results. Simply apply the ID to the jQuery object.
3. When you assign an ID to an HTML element it cannot begin with a number character with any HTML version before HTML5. It must begin with an alphabetic character. With HTML5 this can be any non-whitespace character. For details refer to: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

PS: A final issue with the sample code is an LI cannot be applied to the BODY. According to HTML requirements it must always be contained within a list, i.e. UL or OL.