# Creating a jQuery object from a big HTML-string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big HTML-string containing multiple child-nodes.

Is it possible to construct a **jQuery** DOM object using this string?

I've tried `$(string)` but it only returns an array containing all the individual nodes.

Imtrying to get an element which i can use the .find() function on.

Comment: Where is the HTML, what do you want to construct with it?  You may want to look at the .find() function: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: A jQuery object *is* an array-like object containing all the nodes. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Where is 'this string'? what string?

Comment: Take a look here,I think it is what you want  http://stackoverflow.com/q/759887/474535

Comment: I have to pass the element from one WebView to another through a string, the string would just be the HTML source of that element. I think i might have missunderstood what a jQuery object is.

Comment: No one worked for me. This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30677065/3957754

Answer (score 242, accepted):

### Update:

From jQuery 1.8, we can use [$.parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/), which will parse the HTML string to an array of DOM nodes. eg:

```
var dom_nodes = $($.parseHTML('<div><input type="text" value="val" /></div>'));

alert( dom_nodes.find('input').val() );
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmsan9fq/)

---

```
var string = '<div><input type="text" value="val" /></div>';

$('<div/>').html(string).contents();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/273/)**

#### What's happening in this code:

- `$('<div/>')` is a fake `<div>` that does not exist in the DOM
- `$('<div/>').html(string)` appends `string` within that fake `<div>` as children
- `.contents()` retrieves the children of that fake `<div>` as a jQuery object

#### If you want to make `.find()` work then try this:

```
var string = '<div><input type="text" value="val" /></div>',
    object = $('<div/>').html(string).contents();

alert( object.find('input').val() );
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/276/)**

Comment: @user1033619 you can perform `.find()` operation also, check the demo

Comment: But how if `string = '<input type="text" value="val" />'`

Comment: If you can do `$("<div/>")`, why can't you do `$(string)`?

Comment: With more complex HTML I needed to remove .contents to get this to work.
https://jsfiddle.net/h45y2L7v/

Comment: You don't want to do $(string) because you need a wrapping div to get the contents of. You'll be getting the contents of the div, which will be your input.

Comment: What if the HTML string you are using is a complete HTML document? E.g. `<html><body><span>Hello</span></div></body></html>`? That doesn't seem to work at all!

Comment: @fdrv If you have that kind of string use the following code: 

var abc = $($.parseHTML(<input type="text" value="val" />));
alert(abc.val());

Answer (score 127):

As of jQuery 1.8 you can just use parseHtml to create your jQuery object:

```
var myString = "<div>Some stuff<div>Some more stuff<span id='theAnswer'>The stuff I am looking for</span></div></div>";
var $jQueryObject = $($.parseHTML(myString));
```

I've created a JSFidle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/MCSyr/2/

It parses the arbitrary HTML string into a jQuery object, and uses find to display the result in a div.

Comment: I find this answer far better, since this don't have to use a ghost div element.
$.parseHtml ftw.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me when I wanted then then to $jQueryObject.find(), I presume because it wasn't added to the dom at that point.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald -- find should work without the content being added to the dom. If you take a look at my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/MCSyr/2/), I'm calling find on the jQuery object, and it returns a result as expected:

$jQueryObject.find("#theAnswer").html()

Comment: @kiprainey interesting, I'll dig out the example it didn't for me on and see if there was something else afoot. It was written inside a TypeScript module inside a load of other logic, could well have been a different issue! My apologies.

Comment: Worth mentioning that parseHTML was added in **jQuery 1.8**

Comment: This still breaks for certain queries unless you wrap it in a ghost div. Changing the above example: http://jsfiddle.net/ykwd8d01/ - but works if you wrap it in a ghost div: http://jsfiddle.net/g9d81y1x/

Comment: I had to use filter not find on $jQueryObject

Comment: This will also yeild the same result `$(string).find("#theAnswer").html()`  
http://jsfiddle.net/cxf57ha4/

Comment: @kiprainey what if I want to extract the HTML after performing operations like `remove()`? When I do `jQueryObject.html()` it does not return HTML at all

Answer (score 13):

```
var jQueryObject = $('<div></div>').html( string ).children();
```

This creates a dummy jQuery object in which you can put the string as HTML. Then, you get the children only.

Comment: ive tried this, but it doesnt work with the .find() function i have to use later.

Comment: @user1033619 you got to use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a great library called [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) designed specifically for this.

> Fast, flexible, and lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>');

$('h2.title').text('Hello there!');
$('h2').addClass('welcome');

$.html();
//=> <h2 class="title welcome">Hello there!</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following for my HTML templates:

```
$(".main").empty();

var _template = '<p id="myelement">Your HTML Code</p>';
var template = $.parseHTML(_template);
var final = $(template).find("#myelement");

$(".main").append(final.html());
```

Note: Assuming if you are using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

the reason why $(string) is not working is because jquery is not finding html content between $(). Therefore you need to first parse it to html.
once you have a variable in which you have parsed the html. you can then use $(string) and use all functions available on the object

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
$($.parseHTML(<<table html string variable here>>)).find("td:contains('<<some text to find>>')").first().prev().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I have another simple answer. jQuery has moved up quite a few versions and I'm on 1.13.x

Not being an expert jQuery programmer, I näively used:

```
var el = $( "#thecontainer" ).append( "<legit, lengthy html>" );
```

And presto! It worked: `el` is now a fully operational jQuery dom element.

I have been testing it out over the past couple of days and it seems to work as expected.