# How to construct a jQuery object from HTML with leading \n \t \r and spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string with HTML from the website like:

```
\n
<div>
\t<div>
...
\t</div>
</div>
```

If I construct a jquery from this by:

```
$(tmpl)   // like $("\n<div>")
```

It will give me error saying `"unrecognized expression:<div>    <div>    </div></div>"`.

I tried using `$(tmpl.replace(/[\t\r\n]/,""))`. It works but does not seem natural to me.
I also tried using `$('body').append(tmpl)`; it does not require a `replace` but I want to change the attr/styles/data before I attach it to DOM. If I attach it first, I will need to select it again.

Is there any way to create a jquery object from this type of HTML snippets without `replace` and before attaching it to DOM?

Comment: To clarify, are \n and \t newlines and tabs, or litteral strings?

Comment: @NathanJhaveri new lines and tabs, not literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047670/creating-a-jquery-object-from-a-big-html-string), where a fake div is created and then referenced by a jQuery object in order to edit attr/styles/data of an html string before inserting it into the DOM. You can use `JSON.stringify()` to see the newlines, tabs, and carriage returns in the jQuery object and that they are preserved after inserting into the DOM. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gQWh5/1/)

Comment: This does not help. I mentioned all this in my post already. It does not work properly when there is a leading \n or \t or spaces.

Comment: You have to create a dummy div using `$('<div/>')` and insert into this using `.html()`. Then you can do what you want with this object. I've updated my answer with a jsFiddle demo.