# JS: function for every ul in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html-lists, each

I have this javascript (jquery), in which I've defined a variable. This variable contains a string which might have one or more ul's in it. I want the script to select every ul and run a function for each of them.

But unfortunately, nothing happens when loading the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var wid_tekst1 = "<?php echo $wid_tekst1; ?>";
    $(wid_tekst1).find('ul').each(function() {
        alert('hoi');
    })
</script>
```

The $wid_tekst1 contains:

```
<p>test tekst 1</p>
<ul>
    <li>testitem</li>
    <li>testitem</li>
    <li>testitem</li>
    <li>testitem</li>
    <li>testitem</li>
    <li>testitem</li>
    <li>testitem</li>
</ul>
<p>test</p>
```

Thank you

Comment: Javascript doesn't support multiline string. If you php variable is like you show use, it will never work.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, I just set it multiline to make it readable. In real, it is just one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ul`s are top level elements in your collection you should use `filter` instead of the `find` method. If you want to use the `find` method you can set the string as `innerHTML` of another element:

```
$('<div/>').html(wid_tekst1).find('ul').each(func);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Didn't know about the filter-method. So to be clear, the find-method will only work on variables defined as html and the filter-method works on all variables? I'll accept your answer in a couple of minutes...

Comment: @user3235648 You are welcome, actually the difference is the level of elements in a jQuery collection. `find` selects _the matching descendant elements_ of the collection's elements and `filter` filters _the elements in the collection_.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the dom directly, if the UL objects exist there.

```
$("ul")
```

Or you could place your html string into a JQuery object like this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047751/3066711

```
$('<div/>').html(wid_tekst1).find("ul")
```