# Creating a DOM element from a complicated HTML-string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to [create a DOM from an HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047670/creating-a-jquery-object-from-a-big-html-string) that includes link, style, script and comments?

In my app, the end user will be pasting some form code, for example:

```
<!-- Start comment -->
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #full_name{background:#fff; }
    /* This is
    another comment*/
</style>
<div>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
Full Name:<input type="text" name="full_name">
</form> 
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
<!-- End comment -->
```

This is the jquery code:

```
$('#html-go').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var html_code = $('#html-code').val(),
        obj = $('<div/>').html(html_code).contents();
    alert(obj.attr("action"));
});
```

I want to load it into a DOM element for parsing but I get an `undefined` error. If the form code contains only that between the  tags, then everything's OK.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7tat4v2/) that shows the error (paste the form code above).

Comment: yes, you can stuff any html you want into a .html() call, and the JS engine will slice/dice it into the DOM. just make sure it's VALID html. if you stuff in bad/broken html, the browser will try to correct it as best it can, and probably not do what you think it should be doing.

Comment: that being said, `obj` will be the div you created with `$('<div/>')`, and it has no attribute. you probably want `obj.find('form')` or whatever.

Comment: Right, right. I completely overlooked that. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your form inside your newly created div:

```
alert(obj.find('form').attr("action"))
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45LhLd57/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#html-go').click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var html_code = $('#html-code').val();
        console.log(html_code);
        obj = $('<div/>').html(html_code).contents();
        alert($(html_code).attr('action'));
    });
```

Comment: you can also get the attribute value directly from html_code variable