# Why is jQuery not turning this html string into a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a template string that I need to turn into a jQuery object so I can parse it and fill out the data.

```
$(function(){

var template = '<h3>Details</h3>' +
    '<ul>' + 
    '<li>Submitted: <span class="submittedTime"></span></li>' + 
    '<li>Submitted by: <span class="submitter"></span></li>' + 
    '<li>Contact Information' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li>Name: <span class="contactName"></span></li>' +
        '<li>Name: <span class="contactEmail"></span></li>' +
        '</ul>' +
    '</li>';


var t = $(template);

});
```

When I try to perform a jQuery operation on them (such as `.find()`), it fails.

Do you have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason but you're not closing yout first `ul`. That could definitively lead to parsing issues

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe — http://jsbin.com/govibe/1/edit?js,console — How are you testing this? Exactly what code are you using when you call `find()`? What result do you expect to get?

Comment: "`t` is inheriting the prototype jQuery methods" — That's because it is a jQuery object. jQuery objects include an array of vanilla elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a jQuery object from a big HTML-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047670/creating-a-jquery-object-from-a-big-html-string)

Comment: What is your problem? What error you get using .find()?

Comment: @Quentin, I know that. But this is not a JQuery object. Or it's not the normal kind in any case. It doesn't have a "selector" or "context' or "prevObject" property.

Comment: @JakeParis — That's normal. You didn't generate it from a selector (so it can hardly have a property that tells you what the selector you used to generate it was!) or an existing document. It is still a jQuery object.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, ok. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I think it actually is, as per [Quinten's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807537/why-is-jquery-not-turning-this-html-string-into-a-jquery-object/33807885#comment55380625_33807537). Try running this script against an HTML document with a `<div class="test">` element:

```
$(function () {

    var template =
        "<h3>Details</h3>" +
        "<ul>" +
        "<li>Submitted: <span class='submittedTime'></span></li>" +
        "<li>Submitted by: <span class='submitter'></span></li>" +
        "<li>Contact Information" +
        "<ul>" +
        "<li>Name: <span class='contactName'></span></li>" +
        "<li>Name: <span class='contactEmail'></span></li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "</li>" +
        "</ul>";


    var t = $(template);
    //console.log(t);
    $(t).appendTo(".test");
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5svLfq4r/ for a demo.

Comment: What you're doing in the fiddle doesn't match your code above.

Comment: Good call.  However, both of those code snippets work, and they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your snippet inside a div element and close your outer `ul` tag. If you run the snippet below, jQuery will correctly output the HTML. I have converted your template into a multi-line statement to make it easier to read

```js
a = $(function() {

  var template = `
     <div>
        <h3>Details</h3>    
        <ul>
            <li>Submitted: <span class="submittedTime"></span></li>
            <li>Submitted by: <span class="submitter"></span></li>
            <li>
                Contact Information
                <ul>
                    <li>Name: <span class="contactName"></span></li>
                    <li>Name: <span class="contactEmail"></span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>`;


  var t = $(template);

  document.write(t.html())

});

a()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you do not have `</ul>` tag

Comment: Being unable to reproduce the problem is not an answer. If you can't, then leave a comment.

Comment: @Jaco I didn't know about multi-line strings. Holy crap have you just saved me so much effort!!

Answer (score -1):

Based on the **[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)**:

> To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be well-formed. Tags that can contain other elements should be paired with a closing tag:

So you probably need to close that `<ul>`.

Also,

> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, [..]
>   the actual creation of the elements is
>   handled by the browser's .innerHTML mechanism. In most cases, jQuery
>   creates a new  element and sets the innerHTML property of the
>   element to the HTML snippet that was passed in.

it may be different on different browsers.