# Make text appear in HTML

Tags: html, typo3

On my page the following **TEXT** is getting displayed:

```
<p>Hello,<br>I am a <a href="http://example.com">text</a></p>
```

It is not appearing in HTML since Typo3 won't allow me to.

Is there a way to make the browser understand that they are HTML tags? Maybe with jQuery?

Comment: It's an encoding issue. I'm not familiar with Typo3, but does it no have a method of allowing you to enter HTML without it being encoded?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have tried almost everything but I couldn't find out how to make it allow HTML. The only way as far as I know would be changing the core file but I don't want to do this.

Comment: Select the element with `JQuery`, get the `innerHTML`, then check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047670/creating-a-jquery-object-from-a-big-html-string

Comment: @randy thank you, this helped me a lot.

Comment: Where is that text coming from? The RTE in the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works:

```
var string = '<p>Hello,<br>I am a <a href="http://example.com">text</a></p></a></p>';
$('.tx-felogin-pi1 > div').html(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the RTE to plain text mode by clicking the <> button.

Comment: Will not work, because TYPO3 filters the HTML tags according the to RTE processing configuration.

Comment: There is no such a <> button for single input fields.