# How to add a new attribute for a HTML element before added to DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Actually it could happen that's the title it's not exactly correct, so sorry.
My problem is the following. I have a variable (what contains html), what it get from ajax response and i would like to add new attribute a few element. And after it insert to the dom.

For example, here this:

```
ajaxString  = "<b>asd</b>";
replaced    = $("b", $(ajaxString) ).css('background','#ff0000');
$("body").html(replaced);
```

But it's doesn't work. I hope, somebody have an idea!

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: what attr are you trying to add where is `$(str)`? it is a bit unclear fix the OP as much as you can

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a jQuery object from a big HTML-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047670/creating-a-jquery-object-from-a-big-html-string)

Comment: Write your code inside $(document).ready(function(){ });

Comment: @Justinas thanks and really similar but not same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a virtual element:

```js
var ajaxString = "<b>asd</b>",
  virtualDiv = $('<div>', {html: ajaxString});

$("b", $(virtualDiv)).css('background', '#ff0000');
$("body").html($("b", $(virtualDiv))[0]);
```

As per your comment you can use this to get all the html of virtual div:

```
$("body").html($(virtualDiv).html());
```

Comment: That's what I want! I have never hear before, like this. But how can I get back the whole string with a "replaced" element?

For example: "<i>qwe</i> <b>asd</b>" and I need to get the whole string not just the "b"

Comment: @Mate then just use `.html()` as :  `$("body").html($(virtualDiv).html());` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the element in a jQuery object first, then amend its attributes before appending it. Try this:

```
$("<b>asd</b>").css('background', '#ff0000').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working fiddle of what you try to achieve

you should use filter

```
var newhtml = $('<b>asd</b><p>asd</p>');

newhtml.filter('b').each(function(){

$(this).css('font-size','50px')
$(this).css('color','blue')

});

newhtml.filter('p').each(function(){

$(this).css('font-size','20px')
$(this).css('color','red')

});

$('body').html(newhtml);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c7a6spaj/

Cheers