# Turning returned data into a jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a promise on a get request in jquery, that return `data` then add it to the page via append:

```
$.get('/get/something').done(function(data) {
    $('#main').append(data);
})
```

The `data` looks something like :

```
<div class="container">
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

How can I wrap that returned data/appended element in a jquery selector and then perform operations on it?

I've tried :

```
$(data).some-jquery-fnc();
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the class selector with the **[`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** selector :

```
$('#main .container:last').some-jquery-fnc();
```

That will always select the last `.container` added to the `#main` by the `.append()` method :

```
$('#main').append(data);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you append only one element and want to bind your actions with an event this might be of use.

```
$(document).on("click",".container",function() { // or on mouseover or any other event you want
// rest of your code to be executed for this particular event.
});
```

Comment: You're presuming he has the ability to alter what the external script is returning.

Comment: @Blazemonger how about now?

Comment: You're still altering `data` without knowing he is able to do so.

Comment: @Blazemonger if you mean the `id="myID"` part then i will change my answer

Comment: @Blazemonger is it ok now?

Answer (score -1):

You can use:
$.parseHTML(data)
or 
$('').html(data).contents();
 For detail, please refer: [Creating a jQuery object from a big HTML-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047670/creating-a-jquery-object-from-a-big-html-string)