# Transforming html (text) to jQuery object : lost value

Tags: javascript, jquery

When transforming html that contains empty span with a outside text to the jQuery object, I loose the text. I can illustrate this with a simple example:

```
var test = "<span></span> someText";
var jq = $(test);
console.log(jq.prop('outerHTML'));
```

This will log only span, without someText (lost).

Can you tell me how could I avoid this? 
Thank you.

Comment: `Also outerHTML isn't a prop` yep, it is: https://jsfiddle.net/ydwd6kcm/

Comment: I stand corrected, I thought props we're for truey falsy values

Comment: Nope, they work for any property of the Element within the jQuery object

Comment: Code still makes no sense...

Comment: You are very helpful Liam, thank you

Comment: That part's true :) @gospodin could you please give a little more information about how you ended up with that string. It would be better to avoid this situation if possible.

Comment: This string is something that I am getting from the external plugins (outside of my app)It is not me who is constructing it and it should not be changed by me. I just want to manipulate it as jQuery object without loosing any data from the initial html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a jQuery object from a big HTML-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047670/creating-a-jquery-object-from-a-big-html-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty clunky and unpleasant but you could parse it thus

```js
var test = "<span></span> spanValue";
//turn it into VALID html and parse it.
var jq = $($.parseHTML(test));
console.log(jq.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

FYI `parseHTML` requires jquery 1.8+

Comment: Not a bad idea, but since the desired result is a unmodified test variable, we should not remove the spam from it. So removing the line that removes span and changing the log line to the console.log(jq.prop('innerHTML')); would give me the initial test value in a jquery object. I am wondering if there is any other nicer solution than parsingHtml. Thanks.

Comment: What you want this for is unclear. If you just want the text `"<span></span> spanValue"` then `console.log(test);` would do it? But I'm guessing there is more to it than that?

Comment: You don't need to append the `<p>`