# Add code to created DOM Elements using live()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set this code on new elements been added by jQuery using live()

```
var frcode = '<iframe scrolling="no"></iframe>';
$('.foo:nth-child(3n),.foo:last-child').after(frcode);
$('.foo:first').before(frcode);
```

I tried livequery plugin but not working good with me

the Livequery plugin i tried to use

```
$(".foo:nth-child(3n),.foo:last-child").livequery(function(){
   $(this).after(frcode);
});

$(".foo:first").livequery(function(){
   $(this).before(frcode);
});
```

Comment: Which version of Jquery you use? New jQuery does not have live, it use on instead

Comment: Also please post full code (better using jsfiddle)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759887/how-to-create-a-dom-node-as-an-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759887/how-to-create-a-dom-node-as-an-object)

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu i'm using 1.7.2 ,,, about the live code will add it in a seconds

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to `DOMSubtreeModified` on a container where you put your created DOM elements into:

```
var frcode = '<iframe scrolling="no"></iframe>';

$('.container').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
  $(this).find('.newElement:not(.processed)').after(frcode).addClass('processed');
})
```

(you could also use 'body' instead of '.container')

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for only inserting new elements, you can also use DOMNodeInserted event.

See example of usage here: http://jsfiddle.net/2YSEP/